# Airplane mode key function (fn+f2) not working and airplane mode light lit

Tags: 16.04, function-keys

I did a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04.1 on an asus x556uak laptop.
I noticed then that the airplane mode key function (fn+f2) doesn't work at all, and also that the airplane mode led is lit all the time.

When I go to network settings and turn the airplane mode on the light goes off, and when turned off the light goes on.
The LED is working reversely.

I have tried to see the output of `dmesg | grep iwl` but nothing appears in the terminal.

Can anyone help with this issue??
thanks for the time.

Comment: I have the same problem on an Asus UX303UA. A partial workaround I've found is that the light will go off (and stay off) after suspending the laptop.

Comment: @freddybob Ok, but here the problem is mainly that the fn airplane button doesn't work at all, after that is solved also the led issue has to be solved. I have filed a bug about this and was told to test the latest mainline kernel , there the fn button works but the led still works backwards: when the airplane mode is activated the led is off and when the airplane mode is off the led is on.